# How to smoothly connect two signals in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to generate two signals which in the end I want to connect. The problem is that the end condition of the 1st signal can be quite different compared to the initial conditions in my 2nd signal. Subsequently it can result in a sudden and unrealistic jump in my final signal. Final signal is the 2 connected signals.

How could I smooth the connection in my final signal?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by connect? Are you saying this as if you have two songs, you want to append two songs together?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know I can connect signals by `cat(2,signal1,signal2)` but I would like for the connection from one signal to another to be smooth.

Comment: Maybe you could overlap them and then have a weighting structure that gradually fades from one to the other - kind of like cross-fading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about some sort of cross-fading:

```
S1 = rand(1000,1);
S2 = rand(1000,1) + 1;

%\\ cross-fade over last 200 elements
n = 200;

W = linspace(1,0,n)';                                    %'

S1(end-n+1:end) = S1(end-n+1:end).*W;
S2(1:n) = S2(1:n).*(1-W);

S12 = zeros(size(S1,1) + size(S2,1) - n, 1);
S12(1:size(S1,1)) = S1;
S12(end-size(S1,1)+1:end) = S12(end-size(S1,1)+1:end) + S2;
```

This was using a linear weighting for the fading, you might choose something else but I think this will sort of work.

Comment: This is probably the simplest and most straightforward option.

Comment: For different lengths of S1, S2 the last line does not work.  Swap S1 with S2 as follows: `S12(end-size(S2,1)+1:end) = S12(end-size(S2,1)+1:end) + S2;`