# Cross fading multiple audio files of different lengths together in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

Greetings I'm trying to cross fade several audio files together *(about 40 files which vary in length around 30 to 54 seconds or longer)*. I'm using octave 3.8.1 (which is like matlab).   The files all have different file lengths.  I found some code which only works if the files have the same length and for just cross-fading two files [cross fade code link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012679/how-to-smoothly-connect-two-signals-in-matlab/23013384#23013384).  How can I cross fade several files that have different file lengths?  **So S2 would be S2=rand(911,1) + 1; or S3=rand(932,1) + 1; or S4=rand(654,1); etc...**

```
S1 = rand(1000,1);
S2 = rand(1000,1) + 1; % so S2 would be S2=rand(911,1)

%\\ cross-fade over last 200 elements
n = 200;

W = linspace(1,0,n)';                                    %'

S1(end-n+1:end) = S1(end-n+1:end).*W;
S2(1:n) = S2(1:n).*(1-W);

S12 = zeros(size(S1,1) + size(S2,1) - n, 1);
S12(1:size(S1,1)) = S1;
S12(end-size(S1,1)+1:end) = S12(end-size(S1,1)+1:end) + S2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I will crossfade two sinus. The first with 1kHz, the second with 2.2kHz. The first sine is 10s long, the second 15s.

I'll start to crossfade after 6s and the fading takes 4s so the resulting length is 6+4+15-4 = 21s long

```
## use FS=44800 to hear it
FS = 44800;

t1 = linspace (0, 10, FS * 10);
t2 = linspace (0, 15, FS * 15);

## crossfade in 4s
cl = 4 * FS;
c = linspace (0, 1, cl);

a1 = 0.5 * sin (2 * pi * 1e3 * t1); # 1kHz
a2 = 0.9 * sin (2 * pi * 2.2e3 * t2); # 2.2kHz

## 100% a1 from 0..6s
s1 = a1(1:end-cl);

## crossfade a1 to a2 in 4s
s2 = a1(end-cl+1:end) .* (1-c) + a2(1:cl) .* c;

## 100% a2 for 11s
s3 = a2(cl+1:end);

## concatenate them
s = [s1 s2 s3];
t = linspace (0, numel(s)/FS, numel (s));

subplot (2, 1, 1);
plot (t , s)
xlabel ("t [s]")
grid on
wavwrite (s, FS, "out.wav");

## plot the FFT
f = linspace (0, FS/2, numel (s)/2);
subplot (2, 1, 2);
plot (f, abs (fft (s))(1:numel(s)/2));
grid on
xlabel ("f [Hz]")
```

[image: Plot of resulting file + FFT]

And here a spectrogram. You can clearly see the crossfading

[image: Spectrogram of crossfade]